# Debug an Application as part of a solution

Tags: vb.net, solution

I have a solution which has both a Windows Service and a Windows Application as part of the solution.  I would like to start debugging JUST the application (Forms App).  Is there any way to do this or do I have to separate them entirely?

When I go into debugging now it refuses because I haven't compiled the service and installed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select the topmost entry in the solution explorer part of Visual Studio you can select the startup project in the bottom right properties dialog. That determines which project is executed primarily in a multi project solution.

(German, but should be clear I guess)
[image]